# Javascript timer puzzle

Tags: javascript, networking, timer

This is a weird scenario I just experienced and I am not sure how to phrase the question.

It may be best to describe my application and what it does 1st.

I have an IP camera connected to my router.
I use a C# VLC wrapper to get 10 frames a second using a RTSP protocol.
I then upload to my web server using a [web method] these seperate jpegs to my server.

Then via browser using a javascript timer set to 100ms it renders the image into a HTML image control by calling an ashx page repteadly.

Now this has worked for a few days OK.

Now this is what I have experienced in the last 48hrs.

The images coming from the IP Camera was jumpy. That is to say sometimes the images flow in a timely order and sometimes it will slow down, stop and speed up again to 'catch up'.

I noticed when viewing via a web browser client on another PC on my network that the javascript  timer calls were slow and sometimes stopped for periods of time. I used Google Chrome to view how often the ashx url was being called.

I closed down my own applications. Rebooted all my PCs and started VLC application without using the wrapper. Again, the flow was 'jumpy'.  So the conclusion there was that it was not my application.

For some reason I decided to log into my router (192.168.0.1).

Page was not found.

In fact I had to do a complete restart of my router to be able to access my router 'page'.

As soon as I did this everything worked OK again.

So, the 2 questions I have is (1) why could I not access my router through that IP address and (2). Why was my javascript timer crashing to a stand-still?

Like I said this is a weird scenario and I would not blame anyone for wanting to close or vote down this question.

But on the off-chance this is a known thing I would like to be educated.

Thanks

Comment: how many images are you uploading per minute? it's possible you just flooded your domestic grade router.

Comment: @Prisoner Hi, it depends.  It is based on a motion detection algorithm but if we say the maximum that could happen then there are 4 images each at 360x288.  10 frames per second x 4 (cameras) x 60 (Seconds) = 2400. but this is the extreme.  Also, even though I am using a timer and async [web method] call I do not upload a new image until the previous 1 has finished doing so. I get notification of this in the async_completed event where I set a modular variable. I will now Google 'flooding domestic grade router' Thanks.